# Swipe Feature To go To Next Activity

Tags: android, mobile, swipe

I am making an app where user can make a survey which contains questions, I have buttons to go to the next questions but I also want him to be able to swipe left to go to the next question. How can I implement That? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can implement this feature using ViewPager. Represent all of your question in single fragment repetition under viewpager and tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use viewpager or horizontal recyclerview against activity . A question per activity is not good idea .
Good luck